# Python convert number expressed as percentage to decimal

Tags: python, decimal

I want to check if a user entered a number as percent format (18.06) instead of decimal format (0.1806), and always convert to decimal format.

Currently, I check to see if the value > 1, and if so, divide by 100. This works in my use case, but I can imagine some edge cases where it doesn't work. Is there a better solution?

UPDATE: let's assume it's a float, and therefore all strange characters, i.e. %s, have been removed.

Comment: But you can have `.05%` right? Why is the `> 1` threshold sufficient? You can't know what format they used given just a number - they should provide units.

Comment: Also what if user types 1? It can be 100%...

Comment: Or `1.5`? Is that 1.5% or 150%?

Comment: There are always better solutions imho but definitely check upper and lower bounds, and be explicit to the user about the format of the input. Some example code added below that may or may not be useful. Some good point raised there in previous comments.

Comment: There's no way to do this unless they signify they want it to be a percent (I.E. with a "%" sign after).

Answer (score 0):

Since you likely take the user input as a string(?) you could check the last digit to see if it is a "%"

```
if user_input[-1] == "%":
    user_val = float(user_input[:-1]) / 100.0
else:
    user_val = float(user_input)
```

assuming that you want to keep the original str value as well, otherwise use the same var.

It would be preferable imho to be explicit with the users as to the format that you want the input to be, as (pointed out by @pushkin) vals can be 0.5% as a valid input.

to be clear about the format of the input, then perhaps

```
while True:  # if Py2.7 use raw_input instead of input
    user_res = input("For 5% please enter 5.  For 44.7%, please enter 44.7")
    try:  # handle invalid input that is not a number
        user_val = float(user_res)
        if (user_val >100) or (user_val < 0):  # check upper and lower bound
            print("Invalid entry- outside bonds")
        else:
            confirm = input("{}% to be recorded as your entry- confirm (Y/n) ".format(user_val))
            if confirm.upper == "Y":
                break
            else:
                print("Please try again") 
    except:
        print("Invalid entry- nAn")
```

Someone downed me for this answer even though it's the only one and not marked as duplicate, so if you find it useful please upvote- thanks.

Comment: Also check upper and lower bounds, and ask the user to confirm what your code is about to accept as their input- that way it removes some of the ambiguity which I think is the primary issue here.